# simplify redundant information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is there a way to have the formula eliminate the redundancy.  Can i specify the set of unique cells in a grouping and have the redundant part simplify to one line and have it repeat to all the unique cells. Like an array but perhaps a reverse array

=ArrayFormula(SUM(
IF(OFFSET( $D$97,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/-6),0,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/ 6)) <>"",
OFFSET( $F$97,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/-6),0,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/ 6)))     +
IF(OFFSET( $Y$97,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/-6),0,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/ 6)) <>"",
OFFSET($AA$97,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/-6),0,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/ 6)))     +
IF(OFFSET($DZ$97,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/-6),0,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/ 6)) <>"",
OFFSET($EB$97,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/-6),0,ROUNDDOWN(COUNT($LD$3:$LD$96)/ 6))))

the unique cells are he ones just right of the offset function

Comment: It is hard to reverse engineer your formula to understand what you are trying to do. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168704/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data side-by-side your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2023-04-14**

Use [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535) to specify each sub-operation as a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) defined through a lambda function, and apply those closures to your data, like this:

```
=let( 
  offsetRows, rounddown(count(LD3:LD96) / -6), 
  numRows, rounddown(count(LD3:LD96) / 6), 
  offset_, lambda(r, offset(r, offsetRows, 0, numRows)), 
  sparse_, lambda(a, b, if(offset_(a) <> "", offset_(b), 0)), 
  arrayformula(sum(sparse_(D97, F97) + sparse_(Y97, AA97) + sparse_(DZ97, EB97))) 
)
```

---

Before the `let()` function became available in Google Sheets, you had to use a "naked", `lambda()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    offsetRows, numRows, 
    sum( 
      if( 
        offset(D97, offsetRows, 0, numRows) <> "", 
        offset(F97, offsetRows, 0, numRows), 
        0 
      ) + 
      if( 
        offset(Y97, offsetRows, 0, numRows) <> "", 
        offset(AA97, offsetRows, 0, numRows), 
        0 
      ) + 
      if( 
        offset(DZ97, offsetRows, 0, numRows) <> "", 
        offset(EB97, offsetRows, 0, numRows), 
        0 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    rounddown(count(LD3:LD96) / -6), 
    rounddown(count(LD3:LD96) / 6) 
  )  
)
```